# How to show using dummy variables

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm completely stumped on how to do this question, the chapter from where it's from is called Definite Integrals, but it talks about using dummy variables:

> Show that
>   $$\int^a_{-a}f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^af(x)\,\mathrm dx+\int_0^af(-x)\,\mathrm dx$$

I'm pretty sure that you can bring out the (-) in $\displaystyle\int_0^af(-x)\,\mathrm dx$ to make is $-\displaystyle\int_a^0f(x)\,\mathrm dx$, but how would I show this using a dummy variable?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The right hand side is $\int_{-a}^a f(x) dx$, which isn't the same as the left hand side.

Comment: Is it $\cdots + \displaystyle\int_{0}^{a}f(-x)\,\mathrm dx$ or $\cdots + \displaystyle\int_{a}^{0}f(-x)\,\mathrm dx$? There's an ambiguity in the question.

Comment: I'm looking at the question right now, it clearly states, on the right hand side, $\int_0^af(x)dx+\int_0^af(-x)dx$

Comment: @JPi, sorry i was having trouble formatting the left hand side, it's all fixed now

Comment: Ok, but then you say "... bring out the (-) in $\int_{\mathbf{{a}}}^{\mathbf{{0}}} f(-x)\,\mathrm dx$ ...". So something is wrong.

Comment: @an4s ah i see my error, thanks for pointing it out. I've made the correction to that part now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

$$\int^a_{-a}f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_{-a}^0f(x)\,\mathrm dx+\int_0^af(x)\,\mathrm dx$$

we need to show that

$$\int_{-a}^0f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^af(-x)\,\mathrm dx$$
Let $ u = -x $.  Then $du = -dx$ and

$$ \int_{-a}^0f(x)\,\mathrm dx=-\int_{a}^0f(-u)\,\mathrm {du}=\int_0^af(-u)\,\mathrm du$$
where $u$ is the  "dummy variable" of integration. Therefore, replace $u$ with $x$.